# How to fix this build error in AUR with gradle (probably related to permissions)

Tags: linux, gradle, arch

I am trying to install an AUR package in arch linux.

I get the following problem, I think it's a permissions problem.

```
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the User Manual chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/5.6.4/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Process command line: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk/bin/java --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.prefs/java.util.prefs=ALL-UNNAMED -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xms256m -Xmx512m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant -cp /home/user/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-5.6.4-all/ankdp27end7byghfw1q2sw75f/gradle-5.6.4/lib/gradle-launcher-5.6.4.jar org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon 5.6.4
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not create service of type ClassLoaderRegistry using GlobalScopeServices.createClassLoaderRegistry().

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
==> ERROR: A failure occurred in build().
    Aborting...
```

I tried:

> sudo chmod -R 750 ~/.gradle

without success

Answer (score 0):

```
rm -rf ~./gradle
```

fixed it for me